# What is __GNU LesserC__, __GNU LesserG__?

Tags: c++, xbase

I found following code in library I'm trying to compile

```
#ifdef __GNU LesserC__
    __attribute__((packed))
#endif
```

and

```
#ifdef __GNU LesserG__
#pragma interface
#endif
```

What the hell is `__GNU LesserC__`? Why is there the space, `#ifdef` afaik doesn't support anything like this. I trying googling it but I only found source code using it, no explanation what it is (was) supposed to do.

Most patches I found fix it by

```
- #ifdef __GNU LesserC__
+ #ifdef __GNU_LesserC__
```

but I would like to know what this actually is.

Oh, and the library is [xbase](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xdb/).

Comment: If that is the correct fix, then it is probably a typo.

Comment: it's consistent typo across about 20 files.. and gcc warns about it, so it's hard to believe it wasn't done on purpose

Comment: And google does indeed find more instances of it. However, this question is now the first result, and it doesn't yet have an answer. (I have no idea).

Comment: @BoBTFish heh it's a bit scary how fast can google index stuff :D